# MySQL to select records with one duplicate and one distinct value

Tags: mysql, sql

been struggling with a SELECT SQL query...

I have a table `user`

```
id  |  name    | is_regular |....other columns
1   |  user1   |      1     |
2   |  user2   |      1     |
3   |  user1   |      0     |
```

I need to create a SELECT query which gives me users with the **same** `name` but **different** `is_regular` value.

`is_regular` is a flag that can have `0` or `1` therefore I tried with having clause: `HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT is_regular) = 2` yet I am unable to fetch duplicate names.

So, the query would fetch something like...

```
id  |  name    | is_regular |
1   |  user1   |      1     |
3   |  user1   |      0     |
```

or even better

```
id  |  name  
1   |  user1
```

Is there a way to do so without subquery?

Comment: Sample data and desired results would help.

Answer (score 0):

Does this do what you want?

```
select name
from user u
group by name
having min(is_regular) <> max(is_regular)
```